# Pretty-print nested json with jq

Tags: json, jq, pretty-print

Using jq, how do I pretty-print

```
echo '{ "my_key": "my_val", "next_key": "next_val", "schema": "{\n  \"name\": \"bucket_name\"\n}" }'
```

resulting in

```
{
  "my_key": "my_val",
  "next_key": "next_val",
  "schema": {
    "name": "bucket_name"
  }
}
```

I can escape the newlines and get some kind of useful output but I don't want to interfere with the source json, for example

```
echo '{ "my_key": "my_val", "next_key": "next_val", "schema": "{\\n  \\"name\\": \\"bucket_name\\"\\n}" }' | jq '(.schema | fromjson) as $s | .schema = $s'
```

In this example, I am also stuck with a hard-coded key `schema` key when there are other keys in my json with nested json and I don't know the names of those keys.

Is there a way to do this generically for any key name that contains nested json without escaping the escapes or specifying the keys?

Comment: Your example with hard-coded field names could be simplified to `jq '.schema |= fromjson'`. You could even add more fields to the LHS if needed: `jq '(.schema1, .schema2) |= fromjson'`.

Comment: That's not pretty-printing; that's changing the value of the `schema` key from a JSON string to a JSON object.

Comment: Yes, I realise that. The motivation here is that I have a terraform plan for BigQuery as json. I want to diff consecutive versions of the plan to see what parts of the json string are changed and I need that string as an object so it can be prettified otherwise the entire string will always report a diff. I suppose I could tackle the task in multiple steps but the suggestion below looks promising and I will try tomorrow when I get in front of my keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `walk` through the document tree, `try` to convert `strings` using `fromjson`, and `catch` failures by falling back to the original item:

```bash
echo … | jq 'walk(strings = (. as $s | try fromjson catch $s))'
```

```json
{
  "my_key": "my_val",
  "next_key": "next_val",
  "schema": {
    "name": "bucket_name"
  }
}
```

---

To exempt from conversion certain strings that unwillingly happen to qualify as a valid JSON-encoding (like `"true"` or `"123"`), add further conditions covering a distinction. For instance, to only decode strings that represent `objects`, you could go with:

```bash
jq 'walk(strings = (. as $s | try (fromjson | objects // $s) catch $s))'
```

Comment: What if `my_val` contains only digits and OP wants to keep it as string, instead of converting it to integer ?

Comment: @Philippe You could also check the `type` of a successful conversion, and reject it (ie. still fall back to `.`) in case it's a number, or not an object, etc.

Comment: Looks good. Not able to test atm. Can I avoid escaping the escapes inside the json string (of my schema key) with your approach @pmf

Comment: @LiamCaffrey Yes, these solutions are intended to be used on the original input, i.e. `echo '{ "my_key": "my_val", "next_key": "next_val", "schema": "{\n  \"name\": \"bucket_name\"\n}" }'`.

Comment: My original json string should have included a list of dicts as the nested json string:
`echo '{ ... "schema": "[{\\n  \\"name\\": \\"bucket_name\\"\\n}]" }' | jq 'walk(strings = (. as $s | try fromjson catch $s))'`

The other approach you suggested `echo ... | jq 'walk(strings = (. as $s | try (fromjson | objects // $s) catch $s))'` leaves the json string containing the list of dicts unprettified.

I can see the benefit of the `fromjson | objects` approach on preserving numeric values as strings. Is there a way to combine the 2 features (i.e. list of dicts and quoted numerics)?

Comment: @LiamCaffrey I'm not sure if I understand your follow-up question. If you want to convert objects AND arrays, just change `objects` to `iterables`.

Comment: Bingo, that's it! Honestly, `jq` is incredibly powerful. I appreciate your help very much. Tnx